# Can't import numpy anaconda

Tags: python, numpy

When I try to run this: `import numpy as np` in python I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kevin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "/home/kevin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .mtrand import *
ImportError: /home/kevin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

I am running ubuntu 16.04 and have 2 python installations. I have also installed anaconda:

```
kevin@phantom:~$ which python
/home/kevin/anaconda2/bin/python
```

I did a `conda update --all` and I now have:

```
kevin@phantom:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Usually python --version command gives Anaconda version number like Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit). How did you get anaconda custom version? That raises a red flag.

Comment: @Hun I did conda update --all

Comment: If I were you I would reinstall anaconda from scratch. And make sure it doesn't have a custom version but have some standard anaconda version number.

Comment: @Hun doing this now, will reply with the version number and if it works

Comment: @Hun Wow, I did nothing but reinstall (this was like the 3rd time I reinstalled it) and it worked... Only thing different was me removing the last line in the .bashrc pertaining to the path for anaconda2

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled anaconda and it worked for some reason...

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. It's the OP telling us what solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new environment in anaconda and installed numpy in the new env. It worked.